# how to publish on pages and groups where facebook where I granted php API permission

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Friends, I have a problem that is spinning around me. I am learning to use the Facebook API, I have 24 hours with this and I am already understanding how it works, I feel a little sorry because in reality it is easy the problem is that I do not understand much English so it is difficult for me.

The specific question is: How do I automatically publish in the selected groups and pages when I log in with Facebook? For example, of the following groups that I manage, I only select one.

[image]

The problem is that when the group is posted, the group id is necessary, using this code snippet.

```
$response = $this->fb->post('/123456789/feed', $linkData, $accessToken);
```

So? The specific question, How do I get that list of groups (and also for the pages) to which I granted permission to be able to (it occurs to me), go through an array and do the post automatically.

Right now I am clear about the following points:

1.- I need to create an app: https://developers.facebook.com/

2.- Have the Facebook SDk installed: https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk

3.- My class has saved these permissions and this configuration:

```
require_once "/../vendor/autoload.php";
    class facebookController{
        private $appid ='XXXXX';
        private $appsecret='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
        public $fb;
        public $helper;
        public $permisos = ['email',  'manage_pages', 'publish_pages' , 'publish_to_groups', 'user_posts', 'groups_access_member_info'];
        public $callbackurl = 'http://localhost/misitio.com.mx/auth/fb-callback.php';
        public $loginurl;



        function __construct(){
            $this->fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
              'app_id' => $this->appid,
              'app_secret' => $this->appsecret,
              'default_graph_version' => 'v3.2',
            ]);
            $this->helper = $this->fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
            $this->loginurl = $this->helper->getLoginUrl($this->callbackurl, $this->permisos);
        }
    }
```

4.- I must obtain the Access Token, it can be debugged here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v3.2

```
$this->helper = $this->fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
    $accessToken = $this->helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
```

5.- For some cases I need the user_id, I already have it saved:

```
$oAuth2Client = $this->fb->getOAuth2Client();
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
$userid = $tokenMetadata->getUserId();
```

6.- To post for example in a group, I use the following and this is where the inconvenience is: (Based on the official documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3. 2 / user / groups)

```
public function toPost($titulo, $url){
    $empresa = new configuracionController();
    $userid=$empresa->getFbUserId();
    $accessToken = $empresa->getFBToken();



    try {
      // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
      $this->fb->post('/123456789/feed', $url, $accessToken);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();


}
```

From already thank you very much.

Comment: `/me/pages`, `/me/groups`

Comment: Can you share me more information please? Do you have the documentation link?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/ (not /pages/, sorry), and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/

Comment: Thanks for your help, it doesn't help me much, that link had already been found, the problem now is that I don't know how to access the id of the groups to do a foreach and post.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ojmvm9

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ojmvr4